# Move a point from A to B in 2D space

Tags: javascript, game-physics, gravity

I'm writing a small space game, but I'm stuck at moving my ship in a nice way from point A to point B in open 2D space.

My first problem with the solution below is that my ship never comes to a complete stop. It gets close, but it keeps vibrating around point B forever.
My second problem is that if I snap it to B when it gets close, the sudden stop looks fake and bad as well.

I think I would like the ship to speed up, travel and slow down just before it stops exactly at point B without any bouncing, but I have no idea how to accomplish that in a good way. Also, if there is some "right" way to move a ship from point A to point B in 2D space that I haven't considered, other ideas are very welcome.

```
if(player.x < destination.x) {
    if(player.velocityX < player.speed) {
        player.velocityX += 10;         
    }
} else {
    if(player.velocityX > -player.speed) {
        player.velocityX -= 10;
    }
}

if(player.y < destination.y) {
    if(player.velocityY < player.speed) {
        player.velocityY += 10;         
    }
} else {
    if(player.velocityY > -player.speed) {
        player.velocityY -= 10;
    }
}

// Friction.
player.velocityX *= 0.9;
player.velocityY *= 0.9;

player.x += player.velocityX;
player.y += player.velocityY;
```

Note that this solution doesn't use trigonometric functions for a straight path from A to B yet, but that shouldn't affect the question I think.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you know where B is beforehand, or do you just want it to halt when it is slow enough? If the latter, the snapping you tried should work if you just reduce the threshold to determine when to stop to a low enough value.

Comment: I know both points A (`player.x`,`player.y`) and B (`destination.x`,`destination.y`) in the example above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution where I increase the `Friction` once the player passed it's destination point, making the ship finally slow down to 0 without snapping to point `B`.